# publish_actions vs publish_stream issue while submitting open graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have my application up which asked for the following permissions:

```
email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,offline_access
```

I've implemented open graph now and tested it. It works perfectly, but after submission I have the following message from facebook

> Your code is currently configured to publish a stream story. You must
>   change your code so that when the test user triggers the action it
>   produces an open graph story. Please make the appropriate changes and
>   resubmit.

From this [blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/) post on facebook dev blog from april, it seems that 'publish_actions' is a subset of 'publish_stream' based on that I have some questions.

1. If that is true why do I need the publish_actions permission?
2. Do I need to take publish_stream out and put in publish_actions? But my game uses publish_stream to publish images from the game to albums. Which it will still be doing. What do I do about that?
3. How do I ask users for publish_actions at run time for these permissions if required and authenticate them without a reauthentication or reload. Any resources on that?

And for clarity here is my open graph publishing code

```
FB.api(
        '/me/'+fAction,
        'post',
        sObject,
    function(response) 
    {
           if (!response || response.error) 
           {
              for (var prop in response) 
              {
                console.log(response[prop]);
                callbackToFlash(0);
              }
           } else 
           {
              console.log('success'+object);
              callbackToFlash(1);
           }
        }
    );
```

Comment: The message does not say that you have the wrong permission (publish_actions is a subset of publish_stream), but that you are using the wrong kind of publishing – a normal stream post, instead of an Open Graph action. If you don’ know the difference, please read the docs.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code, I'm using for publishing.

Comment: As CBroe said, its not about your permission issues. its about the way you publish open graph actions. i think currently your app automatically publishing story to users timeline or feed, this supposed to trigger by user like show Yes / No button and based on the user action it will appear.

Comment: The current actions is triggered when the user buys an item. It is triggered inside the game. The user takes an explicit action and the game publishes a story. (Flash Game)

Comment: in the same page, also check Zachary Allia, question and Lu Chen answer.

Comment: I checked my app page settings (fb) they ask for photos,publish_action and email permissions. That is also reflected on my app page. The stream permissions like mentioned in the article come in the second screen. So that's already taken care of. 

The error from fb seems to be that I'm not using the right method for posting. (Code that I've put in the question) which seems to be the right code.